# Where can I buy Suzaku Kururugi's sunglasses?

Tags: code-geass, merchandise

Somebody tell me where I can get them on the internet please? I'm looking for any and all sites where you find them for sale. I've looked vigorously, but I need to be sure that their existence is only a dream before I give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also were unable to find a direct re-seller for those glasses. I did however find something very similar on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/nl/listing/168888764/anime-noriaki-kakyoin-jojos-bizarre?ref=shop_home_active_6). It also seems this person accepts custom requests, so you could also contact him for a custom design if necessary.

[image]